# java code won't compile warehouse

Tags: java

I am having trouble figuring out how to get the method `purchaseItems(Warehouse w[])` to work.
Any suggestions as to whether I am passing the `w[]` array correctly through the nested for loops?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class WarehouseTest
{



    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String dataArray[][] = {{ "2200", "10", "5", "5", "First Street", "Dallas", "Texas", "76000"},
                    { "5550", "12.75", "2", "3", "Mitchell Drive", "Arlington", "Texas", "76019"},
                    { "12000", "17.50", "6", "7", "Jones Blvd", "Burleson", "Texas", "76120"},
                    { "7235", "22.35", "54", "80", "Smith Circle", "Keller", "Texas", "75020"},
                    };

        Warehouse wArray[] = new Warehouse[4];

        wArray = createWarehouses(dataArray);



        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, purchaseItems(wArray));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, printWarehouses(wArray));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, printWarehouseCharge(wArray));

    } 


    public static Warehouse[] createWarehouses( String a[][])
    {
        Warehouse w[] = new Warehouse[a.length];

        for( i=0; i<w.length; i++)

        {

            w[i] = new Warehouse(Integer.parseInt(a[i][0]), 
                        Double.parseDouble(a[i][1], 
                        Integer.parseInt(a[i][2]),
                        Integer.parseInt(a[i][3]),
                        new Address(a[i][4]), 
                        (a[i][5]), 
                        (a[i][6]),
                        (Integer.parseInt(a[i][7]))));  

        }

        return w;



    } 


    public static String purchaseItems(Warehouse w[])
    {

        Sring msg = "";

        String data[][] = {{ "Dallas", "1", "2"},
                   { "Arlington", "0", "5"},
                   { "Burleson", "3", "0"},
                   { "Keller", "10", "25"},
                   { "Dallas", "5", "0"},
                   { "Arlington", "0", "1"},
                   { "Burleson", "2", "4"},
                   { "Keller", "0", "30"},
                  };


        for( int i=0; i<data.length;i++)
        {
            for(w=0; i<w.length; w++)
            {

                if (w[i].getAddress().getCity.equals(data[i][0]))   
                {

                 String msg += String.format("$%.2f"\n, (w[i].purchaseTelevision(Double.parseDouble(data[i][1], 599.0) + w[i].purchaseComputer(Double.parseDouble(data[i][2], 759.0));

                }
            }

        }

        return msg;

    } 


    public static String printWarehouses(Warehouse w[])
    {
        String msg = "";

        for(i=0; i<w.length;i++)

        {

            msg += String.format("%s\n", w[i].toString());

        }

        return msg;


    } 


    public static String printWarehouseCharge(Warehouse w[])
    {
        String msg = "";


        for(i=0; i<w.length; i++)
        {

            msg += String.format("$%,.2f\n", w[i].calculateWarehouseCharge());

        }

        return msg;


    } 





} // end class WarehouseTest
```

Comment: Can you show the error you have ? that would help us to figure out the troubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified loop:

```
for( int i=0; i<data.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<w.length; j++) // Changed the variable 'w' to 'j'
            {

                if (w[j].getAddress().getCity.equals(data[i][0]))   
                {

                 String msg += String.format("$%.2f"\n, (w[i].purchaseTelevision(Double.parseDouble(data[i][1], 599.0) + w[i].purchaseComputer(Double.parseDouble(data[i][2], 759.0));

                }
            }

        }
```

In the for loop `for(w=0; i<w.length; w++)` you are assigning int value to array object 'w', hence it is causing the problem.